# Native Development Kit (NDK) Build Error?

Tags: java, android

When I'm Build my NDK,I got the this type of error:

[image]

ANdroid.mk file

[image]

Application.mk file

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your Android.mk and Application.mk files?

Comment: @MikeLaren im added both

Comment: Apparently you have more makefiles since you're using `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)`, so you should probably put the contents of those in your question as well. By the way, don't take screenshots of text; just copy-paste the actual text.

Comment: @ATRS you must have a .mk file or some script that makes the builder use "android-19".

Comment: An old question, but woul you get into the habit of posting files as text, not screenshots? You may find that someone wishes to copy and paste some of your code/config to try something out, but using images makes it much more difficult to do that. Also, please do not mark your questions as urgent - all questions have equal importance here. Thanks!